# Extend the height of parbox

Tags: margins, marginpar, dimensions, parbox, dimension-expressions

I have the following command that prints text in the margins:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\solutionpage}[1]{\marginpar{%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{\protect\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep}{~Proof on page #1}%
}}}
```

So the text is "Proof on page *〈number〉*", typed inside a gray box.

How can I make the gray box longer in the vertical dimension?

[image]

On the left is parbox as it is now. I want to add, let's say, 3pt's to its top and bottom.

How can I do that?

This is my MWE:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% page layout
\usepackage{geometry}
% Main matter page layout
\geometry{%
  asymmetric,
  right=65mm,
  textwidth=125mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,
  marginparwidth=43mm,
  showframe
}

%Change margin par font size to footnotesize:
\makeatletter
\def\@marginparreset{%
  \reset@font
  \footnotesize %<-- Change the font size
  \@setminipage
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\solutionpage}[1]{\marginpar{%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{\protect\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep}{~Proof on page #1}%
}}}

\begin{document}
\ldots which resulted in the following insight: For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$. In particular, there are infinitely many primes\solutionpage{27}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minipage will allow to extend the vertical dimension

`\begin{minipage}[position][height][inner-pos]{width}`

The command `\solutionpageXL[<added space>]{<text>}` is defined with an optional parameter to add a vertical space, with the default value = 0pt.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% page layout
\usepackage{geometry}
% Main matter page layout
\geometry{%
    asymmetric,
    right=65mm,
    textwidth=125mm,
    marginparsep=7mm,
    marginparwidth=43mm,
    showframe
}

%Change margin par font size to footnotesize:
\makeatletter
\def\@marginparreset{%
    \reset@font
    \footnotesize %<-- Change the font size
    \@setminipage
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\solutionpage}[1]{\marginpar{%
        \colorbox{lightgray}{\protect\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep}{~Proof on page #1}%
}}}

%****************************** added
\newsavebox{\Mholder}
\newlength{\Dholder}  
\newlength{\addtoholder}    
    
\DeclareRobustCommand{\solutionpageXL}[2][0pt]{\marginpar{%
    \setlength{\addtoholder}{#1}    
    \savebox{\Mholder}{~Proof on page #2}
    \setlength{\Dholder}{\dimexpr\dp\Mholder+\ht\Mholder+\addtoholder}% total height plus addholder 
    \colorbox{lightgray}{\begin{minipage}[c][\Dholder][c]{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep}\usebox{\Mholder} \end{minipage}%
}}}
%******************************

\begin{document}
    \ldots which resulted in the following insight: For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$. In particular, there are infinitely many primes\solutionpage{27}.
    
    \ldots which resulted in the following insight: For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$. In particular, there are infinitely many primes\solutionpageXL[10pt]{27}.
    
    \ldots which resulted in the following insight: For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$. In particular, there are infinitely many primes\solutionpageXL{27}.       
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]